# How does Default::default() work in rust?

Tags: rust

Just to clarify, I am not asking how to use the Default trait or how to implement it. What I am wondering is how a line like

```rust
let a: f32 = Default::default();
```

actually works? What is the implementation of Default::default()?

I would imagine something like this

```rust
fn default<T: Default>() -> T {
    T::default()
}
```

I don't even really know what to search for since this seems to be an associated function to a Trait? Is this a thing? Anyways, I can't find it in the docs of `std::default` so I'm kind of stumped.

Comment: `Default::default()` is just `<_ as Default>::default()`, i.e. "use inference to find the type."

Comment: Can you add that as an answer? I find this very clear to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Default::default()` is just `<_ as Default>::default()`, i.e. "use inference to find the type".

Answer (score 3):

In this context, all of these lines are equivalent. [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) is a trait implemented by [`f32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#impl-Default) which contains the function `fn default() -> Self`. Essentially we are just telling the compiler that we want to invoke that trait. There might be other traits with a function `default` so this prevents ambiguity.

```rust
// Explicitly invoke the f32 implementation of Default.
let a: f32 = Default::default();
let a = <f32 as Default>::default();

// Call the function default for f32 which is resolved to be the trait Default.
let a = f32::default();
```

That being said, `f32::default()` would be preferred in almost all cases since it better expresses what you are trying to do. `f32` does not provide a `default` function on its own and it would be strange if there was a competing trait imported to the module. If that were the case, `<f32 as Default>::default()` is better since it explicitly states which trait implementation of which type we are invoking the function `default` for. Lastly, `Default::default()` can be an easy alternative since it lets the compiler infer the type based on context, but is generally discouraged since it can make your code less verbose.

Comment: `discouraged since it can make your code less verbose.` - IMO less verbose is better

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I'm not sure what you are getting at here. By less verbose, I mean harder to read/understand at a glance and potentially more difficult to maintain as a result. Though, I mostly just brought it up because I remember there being a clippy lint which will warn against this type of usage.

Comment: "Verbose" is not usually seen as a good thing, but I understand what you mean. "Less explicit" might be a better way to phrase it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Locke's excellent answer, here's what the implementation of `Default` for `f32` could look like:

```
impl Default for f32 {
    fn default() -> Self {  // Or f32 instead of Self, same thing.
        0.0f32
    }
}
```